# AlarmManager no funciona cuando se reinicia el dispositivo

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sqlite, android-service

Estoy realizando una aplicación que dada una hora y fecha especifica muestre una notificación en dicha fecha y hora. Todo funciona normal pero el problema surge cuando reinicio el dispositivo, cuando esto ocurre la notificación no salta como es de esperarse, leyendo la documentación de AlarmManager encuentro que esto solo funciona mientras el teléfono no sea apagado o reiniciado y después de consultar como se soluciona esto me encuentro con que es necesario crear una clase que reciba los servicios una vez el dispositivo sea reiniciado (RestartAlarmsReceiver) implemento esto en mi aplicación pero solo funciona cuando reinicio el dispositivo e ingreso a la app antes de que se cumpla la hora y fecha para la alarma, si reinicio el dispositivo y no ingreso a la app la notificación alarma no salta.

Esto es lo que tengo:

MainActivity

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MyAlarmReceiver.class);
    final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, MyAlarmReceiver.REQUEST_CODE, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    long firstMillis = System.currentTimeMillis(); //first run of alarm is immediate // aranca la palicacion
    int intervalMillis = 1 * 3 * 1000; //3 segundos


    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, firstMillis, intervalMillis, pIntent);
```

MyAlarmReciver

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(contexto, MainActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(contexto, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    Uri defaultSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    long[] pattern = new long[]{2000, 1000, 2000};

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(contexto);
    builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)

            .setTicker("")
            .setContentTitle("alarma ")
            .setContentTitle("")
            .setContentText(t)
            .setContentInfo("Info")
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(contexto.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher_background))
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background)
            .setAutoCancel(true) //Cuando se pulsa la notificación ésta desaparece
            .setSound(defaultSound)
            .setVibrate(pattern);

    Notification notificacion = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle(builder)
            .bigText(t)
            .setBigContentTitle("ejemplo")
            .setSummaryText("Resumen de tareas")
            .build();

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager) contexto.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notificacion);
```

Comment: y como guardas la fecha y hora?

Comment: Tengo un método que toma los valores y se ejecuta antes de esos, ese no es problema porque la alarma funciona es decir toma los valores pero no funciona si se reinicia

Comment: pues hay que guardar esos valores un una base de datos

Comment: si, lo hago con sqlite

Comment: Esto puede decirse que ya se pregunto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=BOOT_COMPLETED

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tendrás que hacer otro Broadcast Receiver para cuando reinicie el dispositivo y declararlo en el manifest con permiso para el Boot (inicio):

```
public class RestartAlarmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    ... tu lógica para obtener la fecha y hora
}
```

En el manifest agregar esto:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>

<application ....
<receiver android:name=".RestartAlarmsReceiver"
          android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

</application>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, al parecer solo me faltaba configurar correctamente el manifest